# EF Core query fails by timeout on sorting on Azure SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-core

I have a database hosted on Azure using Premium tier.
Database has a pretty simple table with the following structure:

```
Id PK uniqueidentifier
Timestamp datetimeoffset
TenantId uniqueidentifier
other columns
```

Table has only clustered index.

My app is querying the data using EF Core in the following way:

```
dbContext
.TaskRecords
.Where(r => r.TenantId == tenantId)
.OrderByDescending(item => item.Timestamp)
.Skip(10)
.Take(10)
.ToListAsync();
```

At some point in time when there were more than 200k records queries started failing by timeout.

EF core generates the following SQL query:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [r].[Id],[r].[TenantId], [r].[Timestamp], [r].
[OTHER_COLUMNS]
FROM [TaskRecords] AS [r]
WHERE [r].[TenantId] =@__firmId_0
ORDER BY [r].[Timestamp] DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY',N'@__tenantId_0 uniqueidentifier,@__p_1 
int,@__p_2 int',@__tenantId_0 ='645B38D4-1009-47CF-8519-
182865827F22',@__p_1=0,@__p_2=10
```

which performs well when executing from SSMS or using SqlCommand, but fails with EF.

Adding nonclustered index for Timestamp and TenantId columns didn't solve the issue at all.
Index statistics shown that clustered index had 99% of fragmentation. After rebuilding the index queries started working again. But after reaching 15% of fragmentation queries started to fail by timeout.

Using ascending sorting also works even without rebuilding the index.

What's wrong with EF and why it behaves like that?

**EDIT:**

Rebuilding the indexes doesn't work anymore. So it was probably just coincidence.

**EDIT:**

I spent some time with simple console apps with 1.1.2 and 2.0 versions of EF Core to analyze framework behavior.
Query executes well and almost immediately when calling from Main method, but hangs when query is called from within another method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var context = new DbContext(...);
    var result = context.TaskRecords
    .Where(r => r.TenantId == tenantId)
    .OrderByDescending(item => item.Timestamp)
    .Skip(10)
    .Take(10)
    .ToList(); // WORKS FINE

    result = GetRecords(); //FAILS BY TIMEOUT
}

public static List<TaskRecords> GetRecords()
{
    var context = new DbContext(...);
    return context.TaskRecords
    .Where(r => r.TenantId == tenantId)
    .OrderByDescending(item => item.Timestamp)
    .Skip(10)
    .Take(10)
    .ToList();
}
```

My TaskRecord entity includes 18 properties. When I comment out one random property - second call starts executing with no delay.

Comment: Have you checked the Query Store for the execution plans to track down the difference? It's going to be inherently expensive to re-sort the table for every query, so you'll probably need an index on (TenantId,Timestamp) to make this paging efficient.

Comment: What's the **timeout** value (`context.Database.CommandTimeout`) in EF, a value too low can also make the same query fail.

I would also suggest to check both the queries (from EF and from SSMS) checked through profiler in real-time.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, I created new index as you suggested and monitoring how the system behaves now. No issues so far. However I'm still wondering why it behaves differently when running from EF, when SSMS and SqlCommand queries complete in less than 1second.

Comment: @lamCP, The timeout is set to 30 seconds. I compared execution plans and them looked fine to me, server has to do index scan though. But I still doubt that it takes more than 30 seconds to finish.